# Lost permission to database mysql , how to retrive?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I intalled xampp, and User root didn't set password. I log in as root, but I seem to lost the permission to database mysql. Here's what I got from typing "show database".

mysql> show databases;

information_schema

test

And I can't use mysql database as a result,

"mysql Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

I've tried to reset the password, but It didn't work! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

**There is no password, It's a blank field**. ( *From what I remember* ).

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how can i retrieve the permission to database mysql? You see, I only have permission to 2 databases as above.

Comment: Try to restart MySQL & Apache as it'll reload the permissions. If that does not fix it, go into PhpMyAdmin -> Databases -> beside "test" database click Check Privileges -> edit privileges and make sure they're all checked for all three.